# regex for whole numbers below 75 and below 50

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created regex for numbers from 0 - 100

```
^(100|[1-9]?[0-9])
```

Is this regex validate for every condition like not accepting special characters or something else?

How to design regular expression for numbers(whole numbers only not decimal) in the range of `0 - 75` and `0 - 50` ?

Comment: Maybe regex isn't the best tool for this job? You might want to use `int.Parse()` and `if(number > 75)...` instead.

Comment: You are also not anchoring to the end of input with $ so the re matches 1WAFFLES - Agree that (try)parsing the value as an int is the best way to do this.

Comment: ..unless this is a homework assignment and user4221591 has to use Regex.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers from 0 - 100 you can use something like this:

`^(100|[1-9]?[0-9]|0)$`

For 0 - 75 this should do:

`^([1-6]?[0-9]|[7]?[0-5]|0)$`

for 0 - 50 this one:

`^([1-5]?[0-9]|0)$`

The easiest way to test it quickly is to use some of the online Regex testing tools like this one: https://regex101.com/ for example. This one also explains textually your regex expression.